# How is $\sum_i\langle i|M|i\rangle$ correlated to $\mathrm{tr}(M)$?

Tags: mathematics, textbook-and-exercises, linear-algebra

In the book Quantum computation and quantum information, it says to evaluate $tr(A|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|)$ using Gram-Schmidt procedure to extend $|\psi\rangle$ to an orthonormal basis $|i\rangle$ which includes $|\psi\rangle$ as the first element. Then:

$$tr(A|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|)=\sum_i\langle i|A|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|i\rangle\tag{2.60}$$
$$=\langle\psi|A|\psi\rangle\tag{2.61}$$

I understood that equation 2.61 that uses the special basis $|i\rangle$ described. But **in equation 2.60, how $\sum_i\langle i|M|i\rangle$ is correlated to $tr(M)$ ?** Can you help me with a more detailed description of it ?

Comment: The equation in bold is just the definition of a trace computed in the computational basis $\{|i\rangle \}$ where $i=1\dots d$ and $d$ is the dimension of the system. You can pick any basis since trace is basis-independent

Comment: Note that by definition: $Tr(M) = \sum_i M_{ii} $ and note that $  \langle i| M | i\rangle = M_{ii} $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the comments, so $tr(M)$ is exactly $\sum_i\langle i|M|i\rangle$ as pointed. I just discovered the same question answered with a proof in the physics stackexchange: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/104155/273977